# Pass $(this) to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, this

I am trying to build a media playlist that can advance the credits, play the video and change the title on thumb-hover, end of video and on next/prev click. So I need to write some functions that can then be called together. So like this:

```
    function showBox()
    {
        $(this).parents('.container').find('.box').show();
    };
    
    function hideBox()
    {
        $(this).parents('.container').find('.box').hide();
    };
    
    $('a').hover(
        function()
        {
            showBox();
        },
        function()
        {
            hideBox();
        }
    );
```

The problem is that $(this) does not carry through to the functions from the .hover. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `this` will carry through if you just do:

```
$('a').hover(showBox,hideBox);
```

---

**EDIT:** To address the question in the comment, this will work for any function you assign as an event handler. Doesn't matter if it is an anonymous function or a named one.

This:

```
$('a').click(function() { 
    alert( this.tagName ); 
});
```

...is the same as:

```
function alertMe() {
    alert( this.tagName );
}

$('a').click( alertMe );
```

...or this:

```
function alertMe() {
    alert( this.tagName );
}

$('a').bind('click', alertMe );
```

Comment: Really? That would be the best way I think. Would that work for .click and .bind events too?

Comment: @Drew: Absolutely. :o) It is simply assigning your functions directly as the handlers, and anytime a handler is called, the value of `this` in the handler will be the element that received the event.

Comment: Well then this is the best way to do what I'm trying to do for sure! Is there any downsides to this? How come all these other people didn't suggest this? It seems so easy!

Comment: @Drew: No downsides. This is the simplest approach. The solution from @Šime Vidas is effectively the same, except that he's replacing your named functions with anonymous ones. I assume you want them named for a reason. Frankly, I think it is a good idea to use named functions in lieu of anonymous ones. Adds clarity. Not sure why it wasn't suggested. The plugin example that another user gave seems to only add complexity and overhead without any real benefit. The solutions that pass on some form of `this` as a parameter are also adding overhead without benefit.

Comment: +1 I am...shocked and dismayed that I didn't recognize this to be the case.

Comment: @Phrogz: I must say that I was a little surprised that you and @Šime hadn't offered this solution by the time I arrived. So I was happy to throw it into the mix. ;o)

Comment: @DrewBaker Please accept patrickdw's answer here as the correct one; I'm unsure whether to delete mine or not, as it is helpful to learn about plug-ins and the ability to extend jQuery objects. This answer is, however, clearly the correct one. I'll be editing my answer to note this.

Comment: @Phrogz: I don't think there's any need to delete yours. It certainly is a correct and working solution.

Comment: @Phrogz: I think yours might actually be more useful in my situation. What do you do when you need to execute multiple functions at once? Like $('a').click(doThis, andThis, oneMoreTime)?

Comment: @DrewBaker You can either `$('a').click(doThis).click(andThis);` or you can `$('a').click(function(){ this.doThis(); this.andThis(); });` The latter is more annoying to type, but better performing, as it creates less event handlers.

Comment: @Phrogz: $('a').click(function(){ this.doThis(); this.andThis(); }); returns "this.doThis() is not a function" in FireBug. Also, I don't think $(this) would carry through that way. The multiple event handlers solution might be the best way to do this.

Comment: @DrewBaker Bah, silly me. `$('a').click(function(){ doThis.call(this); andThis.call(this); });` Or if you need the event object: `$('a').click(function(e){ doThis.call(this,e); andThis.call(this,e); });`

Comment: @Phrogz: Great answer! Thanks. I would never have thought to use the .call!

Answer (score 7):

Per @patrickdw's answer, jQuery sets the scope of a callback for an event to the DOM element upon which the event was fired. For example, see the `eventObject` parameter in the documentation for the [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) handler.

*My original answer (below) is useful when you want to create a jQuery plug-in so that you may invoke your own custom methods on jQuery objects and have the jQuery object set as `this` during execution. However, it is **not** the correct and simple answer to the original question.*

```
// Within a plug-in, `this` is already a jQuery object, not DOM reference
$.fn.showBox = function(){ this.parents('.container').find('.box').show(); };
$.fn.hideBox = function(){ this.parents('.container').find('.box').hide(); };
$('a').hover(
  function(){ $(this).showBox() },
  function(){ $(this).hideBox() }
);
```

**Edit**: Or, if (as suggested) you want to add only one name to the ~global jQuery method namespace:

```
$.fn.myBox = function(cmd){
  this.closest('.container').find('.box')[cmd]();
};

$('a').hover(
  function(){ $(this).myBox('show') },
  function(){ $(this).myBox('hide') }
);
```

Or more generally:

```
$.fn.myBox = function(cmd){
  switch(cmd){
    case 'foo':
      ...
    break;
    case 'bar':
      ...
    break;
  }
  return this;
};
```

For more information, see the [jQuery Plugin Authoring Guide](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).

Comment: +1 - This is another great approach which doesn't require the closure.  Good answer.

Comment: The nice, jQuery way of doing it.  Though for the record, guidelines for plugins usually request a single namespace incursion.  So `.theBox('open') / .theBox('close')` would be more to regs.

Comment: Excellent point, @Orbling. I think that guideline is wholly sensible when wrapping up one's own code for a plugin, but perhaps violable for one-offs in a standalone script. I've updated my answer to show one way of doing this.

Comment: @Phrogz: Aye, I quite agree.  As the question looked like it was liable to be a part of a much more substantial endeavour I thought I'd throw it in.

Comment: This is great guys. I'm going to be doing a lot of functions (like nextCredit, prevCredit, nextTitle, prevTitle) so how would I deal with the namespace then?

Comment: @DrewBaker I would probably use a `switch(cmd){ ... }` to handle various disparate commands instead of the cute hack I showed above.

Answer (score 3):

In Javascript you can use [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to execute a function and explicitly specify `this` for it:

```
$('a').hover(
    function()
    {
        showBox.call(this);
    },
    function()
    {
        hideBox.call(this);
    }
);
```

The first parameter given to `call()` specifies the object that `this` will refer to in the function. Any further parameters are used as parameters in the function call.

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify your code to something like this:

```
function showBox(elem)
{
    elem.parents('.container').find('.box').show();
};

function hideBox(elem)
{
    elem.parents('.container').find('.box').hide();
};

$('a').hover(
    function()
    {
        var $this = $(this);

        showBox($this);
    },
    function()
    {
        var $this = $(this);

        hideBox($this);
    }
);
```

Comment: This won't work. `hover(hoverOverFn, hoverOffFn)` -- perhaps move the binding outside, but I'm not really clear what the question is asking :-)

Comment: @pst - caught it as I re-read it, updated to properly set the variable.

Comment: @gddc Now that there's no need to cache it, how about just `showBox($(this));`

Answer (score 2):

```
$('a').hover(function() {
    $(this).closest('.container').find('.box').show();
}, function()  {
    $(this).closest('.container').find('.box').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add parameters to `showBox` and `hideBox` so that they can accept the element, and then call `showBox($(this))` and `hideBox($(this))`.